# Capitalization of job position within a sentence

Tags: grammar, capitalization

Should manager and coordinator be capitalized in this sentence?

Representatives from Jonshore's corporate compliance team, package engineering, and their newly revived package testing lab will be in attendance along with BHRS's National Packaging Safety Program **manager** and the Eastern Region Systems Integrity Safety Program (SISP) **coordinator**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a matter of style (ie opinion) but I would say probably not.

Capitalisation here is used with proper nouns, ie "named things".  If I am the manager of Tesco (a supermarket) then I could describe myself as a Tesco manager.  Tesco is the proper noun here.

However, if Tesco created a named job role called "Tesco Manager" then that whole phrase becomes a proper noun, and so is capitalized.

Looking at your examples, if we ask ourselves "What are the proper nouns here?", then it seems likely it is the "National Packaging Safety Program", "Eastern Region" and the " Systems Integrity Safety Program". "manager" and "coordinator" are not part of these proper nouns, they are simply connected to them in this case, and so should not be capitalised.

However, as I said, it's a matter of style.  For example, BHRS (whatever that is) might have created a named job role called "Systems Integrity Safety Program Coordinator", and so the convention would be to capitalise it.  But, lacking any further information, my guess is that it shouldn't be capitalised.